# Pause & Resume in Kafka Console Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Hi I want to ask you whether kafka console consumer support **pause** and **resume** just like kafka-client.jar or not.
If that possible, how to do it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no pausing. You can simply Ctrl-C to stop the consumer

If you need to track progress for resuming, then pass `--group`